# Makefile of multiple programs rebuilds everytime although recipe 'all' is marked as phony

Tags: c++, makefile

The problem is as described in the title. Every time i type `make`, even if no chagnes are made to the code, these commands are being run

```
g++ -o ./bin/prog1 ./obj/prog1.o -I./include
g++ -o ./bin/prog2 ./obj/prog2.o -I./include
```

Makefile is located at the root of the project folder and the rest of the files are in the `include`, `obj`, `src` and `bin` folders respectively. Here is the Makefile code:

```
IDIR=./include
ODIR=./obj
SRCDIR=./src
BINDIR=./bin

CC=g++
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

_DEPS = 
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ1 = prog1.o
OBJ1 = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ1))

_OBJ2 = prog2.o
OBJ2 = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ2))

_SRC = prog1.cpp prog2.cpp
SRC = $(patsubst %,$(SRCDIR)/%,$(_SRC))

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

all: $(OBJ1) $(OBJ2)
    $(CC) -o $(BINDIR)/prog1 $(OBJ1) $(CFLAGS)
    $(CC) -o $(BINDIR)/prog2 $(OBJ2) $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o $(BINDIR)/*

.PHONY: all clean
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Rebuilds every time" is exactly what you are asking for when you declare the target to be `.PHONY`.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html second paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now, I'm not really experienced with Makefiles yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking `all` as `.PHONY` means that the target will *always* be considered dirty and its recipe will be re-evaluated.
If you don't want that, move the two programs into explicit targets:

```
$(BINDIR)/prog1: $(OBJ1)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

$(BINDIR)/prog2: $(OBJ2)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

all: $(BINDIR)/prog1 $(BINDIR)/prog2
```

Now remaking the `all` target will ensure `prog1` and `prog2` are up to date, but run no further commands.

Comment: This is not right.  Your recipe always needs to create exactly `$@`, not something else.  If the output wanted is `$(BINDIR)/prog1`, then the target has to be `$(BINDIR)/prog1`, not just `prog1`, and the recipe should use `-o $@`

Comment: Right, had not noticed the prefix. Let me fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked! I'd to ask one more thing: Is there a way to add to the DEPS variable every `.h` and `.hpp` file under `include/` or any of its subdirectories without having to hard code each one into the Makefile?

Comment: If you're using GNU make, then yes.  See the `wildcard` function: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html  However, note this is not usually what you want to do (unless, indeed, every source file includes every header file).  If you do this then any time you change any header file, all your code will recompile.

Comment: I should probably make a dependency list with headers for each program?

Comment: Is it possible to combine the two rules `$(BINDIR)/prog[12]: $(OBJ[12])` into one rule, something like `$(BINDIR)/%: $(ODIR)/%.o` ?